# Frequency modulation occurs not in an expected way

Tags: rf, crystal, frequency-modulation

I've built this oscillator. [image]

Then I gave it a DC bias and connected an mp3 player.

Result: I have local fm-stations muted at 90MHz, 90.75MHz and 89.25MHz.

However, at 90MHz an mp3 music is very quiet. At 90.75MHz and 89.25MHz an mp3 music is loud.

Why there's almost no transmitted music at 90MHz?

Comment: Guess : it's probably AM and you're getting slope detection as the FM receiver goes off tune.

Comment: your FM deviation is too large. Try lowering the signal from the mp3 player and experimenting.